# Printing arraylist with toString override and inheritance?

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist, overriding, tostring

Background info: I have a class ellipse which inherits the color from a Shape class and a circle class that inherits from the ellipse class.

In circle and ellipse I had to override the toString method and concatenate a string that displays either "Circle" or Ellipse and the area, perimeter, and color of the shape.

In my main file I need to now print the entire arraylist of shapes "calling each stored object's toString method."

I'm not sure how to tell it to invoke toString for circle when it's a circle and toString for ellipse when it's an ellipse.

```
@Override 
public String toString()
{
    return "Ellipse" + " " + super.getColor() + " "+ this.calcArea() + " " + this.calcPerimeter();
}
```

That is my ellipse toString override method.

Answer (score 1):

Polymorphism is your friend. Dynamic-binding will do that for you if an object is of type circle the circle toString will be called.  If the object is of type ellipse the the ellipse toString will be called.

In other words

```
public Class Shape {
    @Override 
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Shape";
    }
}

public Class Circle extends Shape {
    @Override 
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Circle";
    }
}

public Class Ellipse extends Circle {
    @Override 
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Ellipse";
    }
}

// This is in main
Shape s1 = new Shape();
Shape s2 = new Circle();
Shape s3 = new Ellipse();
System.out.println(s1);
System.out.println(s2);
System.out.println(s3);
```

Will print

```
Shape
Circle
Ellipse
```

Comment: So it's as easy as doing a for through the arraylist and 

System.out.println(shapes); (where shape is the name of my arraylist)??

Comment: "*The compiler will do that for you*" it is not compiler which will handle it, but JVM itself at runtime. Compiler can use only static-binding while what happens here is dynamic-binding (polymorphism).

Comment: What if I'm trying to print out the arraylist but I'm not sure which shape is going to be next in the arraylist? For example the content of the ARraylist might be Circle, Rectangle, Ellipse, Circle. Do I have to do the s.o.p(new Shape()); or can it just be the arraylist's name and JVM handles which shape it actually is and invokes that toString?

Comment: To present polymorphism you should probably invoke `toString` from `Shape` references which will hold `Shape` `Circle` and `Ellipse`. This way OP will see that invoked code of `toString` depends of object held, not reference type itself.

Comment: @Exziled JVM will handle it for you. Why don't you just test it yourself? If you don't have Java compiler installed then there are on-line compilers like http://ideone.com/.

Comment: I just can't run it yet because I haven't even initialized and added data to the ArrayList yet :( doing that method now -.-